# Inheriting Nextjs App component (pages/_app.js) in ReasonReact

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context, reason-react, bsb

I'm trying to implement the React Context API in my Nextjs app using ReasonReact but getting caught out by the bucklescript compiler's way of inferring module names.

To make the context available to the whole tree I need to inherit from the Nextjs App component. The problem is that Next looks by convention for `pages/_app.js` for App component inheritance, but when I use `_app.re` for the filename, `bsb` doesn't produce a Reason module named "App".

In fact, `bsb` prints the following message and ignores the file:

`IGNORED: file _app.re under pages is ignored because it can't be turned into a valid module name. The build system transforms a file name into a module name by upper-casing the first letter`

Is there some way to tell Nextjs to look elsewhere for the App component? Or perhaps a way to tweak `bsb` for just this one file?

That last one seems like a long shot but I don't want to dip into javascript unless I *really* have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to add a js file with an appropriate name that re-exports from a compiled module with a name that BuckleScript does support:

```js
// _app.js
export { default } from './next_app.bs.js';
```

I had to do this to get certain features working with Gatsby. See [this example](https://github.com/glennsl/reasonable-gatsby-starter/blob/master/src/pages/404.js).

Comment: Thanks! We ended up using a symlink for prototyping purposes, which works, but your approach is cleaner for production use. We have run into the need to write some pretty gnarly bindings against the loosely defined parameters to `getInitialProps`. There's also a need to trigger and `await` the `getInitialProps` functions of sub pages, which is going to be pretty challenging. We are planning more towards writing  the App component and other Nextjs-specific code in Javascript, saving Reason for the components and pages themselves (which seem to play more nicely with ReasonReact).